# writing structs to files with c. i got characters like $0@ ϊ ?0@

Tags: c, file-io, struct

I got some weird characters into the file... $0@ ϊ   ?0@ 
what did i do wrong in writing the struct?
Code:

```
int main (){
    struct books {
        char name[30];
        int npages;
        char author[30];
}     book1;

    book1.name = "1000 leagues under the sea";
    book1.npages = 250;
    book1.author = "Jules Verne";


    FILE *book;
    book = fopen("book.txt", "wb");
    /* trying to write the struct books into a file called book.txt */
    fwrite( &book1, sizeof(book1), 1, book);
    fclose(book);
    return 0;
}
```

i changed some things now i get a file written. but i dont' get the npages right in the file.... it's like "Jules Verne 0@ Πώ" ϊ   1000 leagues under the sea  ”"  "

Comment: the struct has some fill/alignment bytes.  those bytes are not initialized.    Note: 2 byte fill after 'name' and after 'author;.  so just make each of those two fields 2 bytes longer.  the int field will still be unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing *binary* representation of your struct data in the file. The strange characters that you see in the file is exactly that: the binary representation of the `npages` field. Yes, it will look like a set of strange characters, just like it is supposed to.

If you want to see the number of pages stored as a human-readable (text) representation of the number, you have to convert it from binary to text representation manually or use I/O functions that will do that for you.

In fact, if you want to see everything represented in human-readable format, you need a text file, not a binary file. I.e. you need to open it as a text file and use formatted-output functions to write the data.

```
FILE *book = fopen("book.txt", "wt");
fprintf(book, "%s %d %s\n", book1.name, book1.npages, book1.author);
fclose(book);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sizeof(struct books)
```

The number of bytes being copied is `struct books` and you never care about the number of bytes needed to store the strings. `sizeof(struct books)` will just have `sizeof(pointers)` included and not the number of bytes held by the pointer.

You can have a `char array` like

```
char name[20]; /* some size */
char author[40];
```

Now `sizeof(struct books)` includes the `sizeof(name) + sizeof(author)`